# Error: Cannot use scalar value as array

Tags: php, exception

```
 Cannot use a scalar value as an array in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\check_array.php on line 12
```

See below my program:

```
<?php
    $array=array(1,2,3,3);
    $array_second=array(2,4,3,6);
    $result_array=array();

    for($start=0;$start<count($array);$start++)
    {
        $result_array[$start]=$array[$start];
        for($start_second=0;$start_second<count($array_second);$start_second++)
        {
            $result_array[$start][$start_second]=$array_second[$start_second];
        }
    }

    print_r($result_array);
?>
```

Please tell me what I have done wrong?
it will be really helpful for me

Comment: Do you really expect us to work with that information ?

Comment: At fist, you did not provide any programme below.

Comment: yes i did but i do not know  why my programme is not appearing

Comment: ok, you did provide the program but it was hiden due to the wrong formating. Select the code and click on the icon for code formatting ;)

Comment: is it appearing right now ?

Comment: Which line is line 12? The line 12 in the code in the question was an empty line.

Comment: where? iam trying to make double dimension array

Comment: does any one have any solution ?

Comment: `$result_array[$start]` is just a number, yet you're trying to treat it like an array here: `$result_array[$start][$start_second]`

Comment: please can you just clear me  about this

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = array(1, 2, 3, 3);
$array_second = array(2, 4, 3, 6);
$result_array = array();

for ($start = 0; $start < count($array); $start++) {
// $result_array[$start] should be array, not scalar!
//    $result_array[$start] = $array[$start];
    for ($start_second = 0; $start_second < count($array_second); $start_second++) {
        // this line caused the error, cant do 0[1] = 5
        $result_array[$start][$start_second] = $array_second[$start_second];
    }
}

var_dump($result_array);
```

Comment: i appreciate for  this anwer

Comment: but i want first array first index element into one dimension array and  second into its two dimension

Comment: Could you post example of input/output ?